# Gulp gulp-compass unable to find my mixins from another file and styles from another directory

Tags: file, sass, gulp, mixins

My sass-compass project is not compiling

Here is my gulp.js file:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/sass/**/*'])
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: 'config.rb',
            css: 'assets/styles',
            sass: 'src/sass',
            image: 'assets/images'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/styles'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*', ['compass']);
});
```

This is my folder structure:

```
foundation/
    components/
        //Some unloaded components that needed top load
    _functions.scss // Unloaded
    _settings.scss // Unloaded
    _foundation.scss // Like as my application.sass file
    _normalize.scss // Loaded
application.sass // Import files
common.sass // Included compass and my mixins (mixins produces error)
defaults.sass
layout.sass
media.sass
mixins.sass // My mixins
topbar.sass
media.sass
```

And this is my application.sass file:

```
@import compass
@import vars
@import mixins
@import foundation/foundation
@import common
@import defaults
@import ui
@import layout
@import topbar   
@import media
```

Here is error from command line:

```
error src/sass/common.sass (Line 2: Undefined mixin 'boxModel'.)
Compilation failed in 1 files.
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error:     error src/sass/common.sass (Line 2: Undefined mixin 'boxModel'.)
Compilation failed in 1 files.
```

Common.sass:

```
/*
Error: Undefined mixin 'boxModel'.
        on line 2 of C:/WebServers/home/sportparad.loc/www/src/sass/common.sass, in `boxModel'
        from line 2 of C:/WebServers/home/sportparad.loc/www/src/sass/common.sass
1: span.highest
2:  +boxModel(1px, 100%)
3:  +inline-block
Backtrace:
C:/WebServers/home...
```

What i need to do to normally compile my project?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: And in last block with code is not common.sass but common.css

Comment: Seems that you're using the `boxModel` mixin but it doesn't exists or you haven't imported the file that contains it

Comment: @AlexGuerrero, mixin boxModel is in common.sass

Comment: Yes, you are using `boxModel` mixin in common.sass but it hasn't been previously created. Where is `=boxModel($arg1, $arg2)`?